# MVC route prefix BUG or not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I discovered strange MVC route prefix behavior and I am not able to figure out what the problem is.
Given following simple code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}

[RoutePrefix("root/{input:alpha}/leaf")]
public class RouteController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route(Name = "name")]
    public ActionResult Index(string input)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200, input);
    }
}
```

When I send following requests:

```
http://localhost:49637/root/COT/leaf = SUCCESSFUL
http://localhost:49637/root/CON/leaf = SERVER ERROR (404 The resource cannot be found.)
```

Only three letters that doesn't work are "CON". WHY?

Regards

Comment: Not something I've ever come across before, but definitely an interesting question with a lot of history behind the answer!